# C# MongoDb Driver .ToList() performance

Tags: c#, mongodb

i'm new in MongoDb, i have a doubt: 
Retrieving a list of documents i need ToList(), my question is, ToList is like in entity framework that kill performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering directly to your questions, YES! When you do a ToList() you are creating a list in memory with the documents retrieved by your query! That's why you only should get a limit of documents.

You can find some examples in this repo: https://github.com/Talento90/repository.mongodb.net (it's not updated)

Try doing something like this:

```
 var documents = await this._collection.Find(e => true).Skip(skip).Limit(top).ToListAsync();
```